# Initial content of Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am displaying a modal using below JavaScript code.

```
        var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
        var initialModalContent = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0].innerHTML;

        $("#plan_templates").click(function() {
            $(".modal .modal-body").html(initialModalContent); 
            $(".modal").modal("show");
        });
```

Modal content will change if user click on a button. I am using below code here.

```
$(".tplan").click(function() {
   var index = $(".tplan").index(this);
   $('.modal').find('.modal-content').html($('.tab').eq(index).html());
});
```

But I would like to show initial content always when the modal show first time. How can I do that ?

Comment: Try using localstorage

Comment: Thanks @NagonusLrak. Why local storage ? Isn't possible to remove content when close and insert content again when open modal ? Thanks.

Comment: `var initialModalContent = '<p>Hello</p>';`

Comment: Thanks @JehongAhn. I am trying this `$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
            $(".modal-body").html("");
            console.log('hello');
        });`. But this is not working.

Comment: since the browser refreshes, it doesn't save the state so it needs to use local storage to save the state and retrieve it later, just like google docs, it saves what you type and the data still in there after the browser refresh... just in my experience and watching tutorials haha

Answer (score 1):

I have the same experience... I tried to use your code and modify it, I hope it helps you

```
<script>

    var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
    var initialModalContent = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0].innerHTML;
    var replacementModalContent = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[1].innerHTML;

    $("#plan_templates").click(function() {
        showModal()
    });


    function showModal() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('first') != (new Date()).getDate()) {
            $('.modal').find('.modal-content').html(initialModalContent);
        } else {
            $('.modal').find('.modal-content').html(replacementModalContent);
        }
        $(".modal").modal("show");
        localStorage.setItem('first', (new Date()).getDate());
    }
</script>
```

You can also try hide/show contents in your modal, you will only see the old content once per day

```
    let $initial = $('.modal-content:eq(0)')
    let $replacement = $('.modal-content:eq(1)')

    $replacement.hide()
    // $initial.show() // initial already showing

    
    $("#plan_templates").click(function() {
        showModal2()
    });

    function showModal2(){
        if (localStorage.getItem('first') != (new Date()).getDate()) {
            $initial.show();
            $replacement.hide();
        } else {
            $initial.hide();
            $replacement.show();
        }
        $('.modal').modal('show')
        localStorage.setItem('first', (new Date()).getDate());
    }
```